# colour is not getting set to workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using java workbook xls but i am unable to set the color.I am using the following code.

```
CellStyle cellStyle = sheet.getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.DARK_RED.index);

Cell celli = row0.createCell((short) i);
celli.setCellValue(list.get(i).toString());
celli.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

I am using the cellstyle but color is not being set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.DARK_RED.index);
cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
```

instead of

```
cellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(HSSFColor.DARK_RED.index);
```